# Index twice in dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm looking at the following code and I'm having a hard time understanding how double index to a dictionary works.

```
var inDT = new DataTable();
// Fill the input table

var oDT = new DataTable();
var dfq = new Dictionary<DateTime, DataRow>;
oDT.Columns.Add("StartDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
for (int i = 0; i < inDT.Rows.Count; i++) {
    var key = (DateTime)inDT.Rows[i][0];
    var row = (String)inDT.Rows[i][2];
    var data = (Double)inDT.Rows[i][1];

    if (!oDT.Columns.Contains(row)) {
       oDT.Columns.Add(row);
    }
    if (dfq.ContainsKey(key)) {
        dfq[key][row] = data;
    } else {
        var oRow = oDT.NewRow();
        oRow[0] = key;
        oRow[row] = data;
        dfq.Add(key, oRow);
        oDT.Rows.Add(oRow);
    }
}
```

// pivot table in oDT

Namely this line.  Is this 2 value both used as key?

```
dfq[key][row] = data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a double index to a dictionary. Only the first `[key]` indexes the dictionary (using [this indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Item__0_)). The second `[row]` indexes the `DataRow` (using [this indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_String_)).

Note that the dictionary is a `Dictionary<DateTime, DataRow>`. `dfq[key]` therefore gets the `DataRow` associated with the key `key`. The index `[row]` then gets the particular thing at column name `row` in that `DataRow`.

It might be easier to understand if you split it into two statements:

```
DataRow dataRow = dfq[key];
dataRow[row] = data;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like
> arrays. The indexed value can be set or retrieved without explicitly
> specifying a type or instance member. Indexers resemble properties
> except that their accessors take parameters.

A Dictionary has an indexer

```
public TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
```

Which allows you to call `someDictionary["key"]` and returns a value. In this case the value is a `DataRow` which also has several [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0), which allows you to access things like `someDataRow[row]`

Putting it all together

```
var dataRow = dfq[key];
var row = dataRow[row];
```

can be shortened to

```
var row = dfq[key][row];
```